# Combine output of two SSH commands, each running wget download

Tags: ssh, download, wget

I found a site that provides things for download which no other site provides.

> Trying not to say what, to avoid answers providing a separate download-link, nothing unlawful friends ;-)

But said site has limits for downloads:

- Maximum 2 connections per IP.
- Maximum 50 KB download per connection.
- At least, it supports resume, meaning my download speed is: 50 KB * 2 == 100 KB

Said limits are far below my internet band-width, but luckily, I have a remote host (so one extra IP, beside my Personal-IP), which means I can download an extra file at the same time, using command like:

```
ssh root@123.45.67.89 'wget -O - https://my-site.com/my-direct-link.zip' >> my-local-download.zip
```

> Above command even shows size-already-downloaded, progress-in-percent, donwload-speed and time-remaining, like:
>
> ```
> 289050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 15%  50K 10h30m42s
> ```
>
> which allows me to see how long it takes to complete.

The problem is, said command uses only one connection of possible 2 connections.
I know `wget` can increase max-connections per server, but I can not use such thing, because then I would need to wait till download fineshes (maybe *blindly* without knowing progress), before I can download on local.

So instead I want to run 2 wget commands parallel, but:

- How can I config first `wget` command to download only until 50% of original file.
- How can I config second `wget` command to download after said 50%.
- How can I combine both half-files back into one 100% file.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question, and anyone knowing better approach is welcome ;-)

Comment: try aria2c instead?

Comment: @jhnc I don't know what `aria2c` is, or how to use it, maybe explain in an answer how that's better (with related command if possible).

Comment: @jhnc A quick search shows "`aria2 can be manipulated via built-in JSON-RPC and XML-RPC interfaces.`", so using it through simple SSH command may not be possible, but I would accept any shell-script doning said "RPC" as answer as well.

Comment: or you could just use its `-x` option - http://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html , https://repology.org/project/aria2/versions

Comment: @jhnc The `-x` option is short-hand for `--max-connection-per-server=`, and `wget` has similar feature already, see edit for why I can't use such features.

Comment: you said 2 connections per ip (so 4 in total - 2 local, 2 ssh). is that not what you meant? Why does what is happening remotely affect what you do locally?

Comment: @jhnc My current-command downloads the output of one-remote-command **instantly**, but if we simply allow multiple-connections instead of splitting into separate files, then how would the SSH-command to download output look like? Self-answer: SSH does not support that, at least not instantly, and we would need to wait till remote-download completes (before we can download locally).

Comment: `ssh user@host 'aria2c -x2 -o file url && cat file 1>&2 && rm file' 2>file` ?

Comment: @jhnc Your command would would not download instantly, but at least waits automatically.